# When shall I use the keyword "assign" in SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

For example, what will happen here if I do not use the `assign` keyword:

```
module dff(q,d,clear,preset,clock);
   output q;
   input d, clear, preset, clock;
   logic q;
   always @(clear or preset)
     if (!clear)
       assign q = 0;
     else if (!preset)
       assign q = 1;
     else
     deassign q;
  always @(posedge clock)
     q = d;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

The general guidelines for synthesizable Verilog code are that you should only use the `assign` keyword for combinational logic, not for sequential logic like a DFF.

Your code example is from the IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 10.6.1 *The assign and deassign procedural statements*.  That coding style, while legal, is not recommended for synthesizing a DFF. In fact, just below the code is this statement:

> NOTE — The procedural assign and deassign constructs are under
>   consideration for deprecation.

Essentially, you should not use `assign` inside the `always` block.

A more traditional code for a synthesizable DFF (with only an asynchronous reset) is:

```
module dff (
   output logic q,
   input d, resetn, clock
);
    always @(posedge clock or negedge resetn) begin
        if (!resetn) begin
            q <= 0;
        end else begin
            q <= d;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

There is no need for an `assign`, and it uses nonblocking (`<=`) assignments.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use the `assign` keywords in the example you posted, then `q` gets written on the next `posedge clock` with the value of `d`. The state of `clear` or `preset` has no lasting affect on the value of `q`. Normal procedural assignments are overwritten by procedural continuous assigments.

The synthesis style of dividing the synchronous and asynchronous behaviors of sequential logic into separate `always` blocks turned out to be unpopular with synthesis tools, and gradually lost all support. It conflicts with the style that requests that variables be written to from only a single `always` block. Also, people get confused between *continuous assignments* and *procedural continuous assignments* because they both use the `assign` keyword.